# a transparent blue color coming on clicking the main nav element

Tags: html, css

I found a strange behaviour on clicking the main menu of the navigation bar 
I have done the navigation in such a way that it shows the sub menus on clicking the main menu item .I have completed it using **HTML** and pure **CSS**.

I have been working on removing that highlighting effect for a long time.Finally I found a solution by removing the tab index from the span ,which has resulted in no border coming up but the drop down also is not coming up.

Here is my code.Can any one help me with a solution?

*HTML*

```
<div id="Latest_Posts">
    <div id="navs">
        <ul>
            <li><span tabindex="1">Latest Posts</span>

                <ul style="padding-top:.5em">
                    <li id="none"></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo $a; ?>"><?php   echo CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/image1.png')." "; ?> This is the Latest Post No.1</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#Profile"><?php   echo CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/image2.png')." "; ?>This is the Latest Post No.2</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo $b; ?>"><?php   echo CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/image3.png')." "; ?>This is the Latest Post No.3</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#Profile"><?php   echo CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/image4.png')." "; ?>This is the Latest Post No.4</a>

                    </li>
                    <li id="none"></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
#navs {
    z-index:4;
}
#navs ul {
    height:24px;
    width:80px;
    list-style:none outside none;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding:1px;
    margin-top:14px;
}
#navs ul ul {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffffff), to(#dfdfdf));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #dfdfdf);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #dfdfdf);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #dfdfdf);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #dfdfdf);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #dfdfdf);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, startColorstr=#ffffff, endColorstr=#dfdfdf);
    border:1px solid #b2b2b2;
    display:none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px 1px #bfbfbf;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px 1px #bfbfbf;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 1px #bfbfbf;
    height:auto;
    border-radius: .3em;
    position:absolute;
    top:24px;
    width:320px;
}
#navs ul ul ul {
    display:none;
    left:168px;
    position:absolute;
    top:-1px;
    width:138px;
}
#navs ul li {
    float:left;
    margin-right:1px;
    width:100px;
    position:relative;
}
/*style for the sub menus*/
 #navs ul li a {
    border:1px solid #000000;
    color:#0065a4;
    cursor:default;
    display:block;
    font:13px Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding:3px 3px 4px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#navs ul li span {
    background:url(../images/blueArrow.png) no-repeat scroll 90% center transparent;
    color:#ffffff;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
    font:13px Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding:7px 14px 4px 3px;
    position:relative;
}
/*division for latest posts hover color change*/
 #navs ul li span:hover {
    background:url(../images/blueArrow.png) no-repeat scroll 90% center transparent;
    color:#beedfe;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
    font:13px Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding:7px 14px 4px 3px;
    position:relative;
}
/* division for contact Us*/
 #navs ul li#special span {
    background: no-repeat scroll 90% center transparent;
    display:block;
    font:13px Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding:7px 14px 4px 3px;
    position:relative;
    width:60px;
    margin-left:-10px;
    color:#ffffff;
}
#navs ul li#special span:hover {
    background: no-repeat scroll 90% center transparent;
    display:block;
    font:13px Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding:7px 14px 4px 3px;
    position:relative;
    width:60px;
    margin-left:-10px;
    color:#beedfe;
}
/*style for main manu popular posts*/
 #navs ul li#arrow_closer span {
    background:url(../images/blueArrow.png) no-repeat scroll 90% center transparent;
    color:#000;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
    font:13px Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding:7px 20px 4px 3px;
    position:relative;
    margin-left: -11px;
    color:#ffffff;
}
#navs ul li#arrow_closer span:hover {
    background:url(../images/blueArrow.png) no-repeat scroll 90% center transparent;
    color:#000;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
    font:13px Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding:7px 20px 4px 3px;
    position:relative;
    margin-left: -11px;
    color:#beedfe;
}
/*this for the top notch in the navigation drop down*/
 #navs > ul > li > ul:before {
    content:'';
    display: block;
    border-color: transparent transparent rgb(250, 250, 250) transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -160px;
}
#navs ul ul li {
    float:none;
    margin-right:0;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-indent:10px;
}
#navs ul ul li a, #navs ul ul li span {
    border:1px solid transparent;
    padding:3px 3px 5px 2px;
    width:314px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#navs ul ul li a img, #navs ul ul li span img {
    border-width:0;
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#navs ul li:hover > a {
    background-color: #36abf6;
    border:1px solid #eee;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#navs img.close {
    display:none;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    z-index:-1;
}
#navs ul li span:focus + ul, #navs ul li ul:hover, #navs ul:hover + img.close {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: js fiddle would be helpful...

Comment: I created one for you. ENJOY http://jsfiddle.net/YAFqN/

Comment: Try `outline: 0` on `#navs` - it's probably a browser highlight for usability...

Comment: @FDL That's right, that code is a usability highlight ;) http://www.outlinenone.com/ 

At Ambily: Btw, you are using id="none" more than one time!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the dotted outline around `Latest Posts`, this can be removed with

```
#navs ul li span:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b7sZ2/)